# Can we get details of installed printer in PC using javascript?

Tags: javascript, windows-7, windows-8

This is an investigation on javascript, have anybody tried to enumerate printer using javascript which support in all browser without any add-on.

I require help in this region.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not possible, and probably won't ever be for security reasons.